# onepage-scroll doesn't move scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I'm using this onepage-scroll script http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.htm. On my site it works okay, but the scrollbar doesn't move as I scroll on page. That's not good, because I use popup.
My probelm is, that I can't see the popup when I click the popup link.

I've cheked that th popup link is working by tuning off the onepage-scrol script.
I think the popup is opening, but because the scrollbar donsn't move the popup isn't where it should be.

I need the scrollbar to move as normal when scrolling.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pthv/fnC42
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any scrollbar there, that defeats the purpose of the plugin - *One Page Scroll let you transform your website into a one page scroll website that allows users to scroll one page at a time.*

Comment: Hi Mark. Okay. 
Do have any ideas why the modal popup dosn't show except if I remove the onepage-scroll script?

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead?